# "Approach to" and "going to"

Tags: prepositions, infinitives, prepositional-phrases

I know that "**approach to**" is a prepositional phrase that it requires a present-participle verb following.

> He **approach to** transitioning students from high school to university.

But, why not "**going to**"?

> I'm **going to** meet you.

Aren't they are same transitive verbs and used to express a movement or moving action?
How can I actually use the "to" as an *infinitive marker* or *preposition* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I know that Approach to is a preposional phrase that it requires a present-participle verb following it.

**Comment**: No, approach to is not a prepositional phrase. It is a noun plus to. /**His approach to** explaining this problem is straight forward/.

2) He approach to transitioning students from high school to university
But, why not going to?

**Comment**: **approach as a verb**: **He approaches students** transitioning from high school to university. No /to/.

Compare the verb form to the noun: **His approach to teaching is very old fashioned**. Approach as a verb does not take to: **They approached the man from behind**.

**I'm going to meet you.**
Aren't they the same transitive verbs and used to express a movement or moving action? How can I actually use the "to" as an infinitive marker or preposition?

Answer: No, in the form /**going to + verb/, going to expresses a future**.

**I'm going to leave now**. It is not introducing a prepositional phrase.

Summary: going to expresses a future and is followed by any verb: **going to see, going to do, going to think**

approach as a verb does not take /to/. Approach as a noun takes to but is not a prepositional phrase. It's just a preposition used with the noun: **A person's approach to life**. It is used to show a direction or purpose.